# In what order (if any) do tasks get executed with await?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am trying to wrap my head around how `await` works, and in what order (if any) do operations get executed in the Queue.I will try to give an example to illustrate my point better.

My simplified example is inspired by [Brad Solomun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7954504/brad-solomon)'s [article](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/#async-ios-roots-in-generators) on asyncio:

```
import asyncio
import os


async def makeitem(size: int = 5) -> str:
    print("Making item", size)
    return os.urandom(size).hex()


async def randsleep(caller=None) -> None:
    i = 0.000001
    if caller:
        print(f"{caller} sleeping for {i} seconds.")
    await asyncio.sleep(i)


async def produce(name: int, q: asyncio.Queue) -> None:
    await randsleep(caller=f"Producer {name}")
    i = await makeitem()
    await q.put(i)
    print(f"Producer {name} added <{i}> to queue.")


async def consume(name: int, q: asyncio.Queue) -> None:
    while True:
        await randsleep(caller=f"Consumer {name}")
        i = await q.get()
        q.task_done()


async def main(nprod: int, ncon: int):
    q = asyncio.Queue()  
    producers = [asyncio.create_task(produce(n, q)) for n in range(nprod)]
    consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consume(n, q)) for n in range(ncon)]
    await asyncio.gather(*producers)
    await q.join()
    for c in consumers:
        c.cancel()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--nprod", type=int, default=2)
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--ncon", type=int, default=5)
    ns = parser.parse_args()
    asyncio.run(main(**ns.__dict__))
```

Expected output (with my comments marked with #):

```
Producer 0 sleeping for 1e-06 seconds.
Producer 1 sleeping for 1e-06 seconds.
Consumer 0 sleeping for 1e-06 seconds. # How did we get to consumer here instead of Making Item?
Consumer 1 sleeping for 1e-06 seconds.
Consumer 2 sleeping for 1e-06 seconds.
Consumer 3 sleeping for 1e-06 seconds.
Consumer 4 sleeping for 1e-06 seconds.
Making item 5
Producer 0 added <13d0061b8c> to queue.
Making item 5
Producer 1 added <9d840aedcc> to queue.
Consumer 0 sleeping for 1e-06 seconds.
Consumer 1 sleeping for 1e-06 seconds.
```

I am mainly confused by the fact that "Making item" happens after calls from the producer and consumers. I would have expected `makeitem` to be called after `await randsleep(caller=f"Producer {name}")` is completed because it is simply the next part to be executed in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would have expected `makeitem` to be called after `await randsleep(caller=f"Producer {name}")` is completed because it is simply the next part to be executed in the function.

The point of using `await` rather than an ordinary function call is that it allows the current coroutine to be *suspended* while waiting for the awaitable to provide the requested value. While suspended, the coroutine temporarily relinquishes control to the event loop, which will run other coroutines or callbacks, or go back to sleep, as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer : ) Does that happen in no predictable order whatsoever?

Comment: @Rey619 I think the runnable tasks are maintained in a FIFO queue, but I'm not sure if that makes it predictable in a practical sense. I think correct code shouldn't depend on the exact order, sort of how correct threaded code shouldn't depend on which thread is woken up first, out of those that wait on a condition.